# Not binding in-app billing service from IabHelper

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to include in-app purchases to my app, but I cannot bind my activity to the in-app billing service.

I have already done all the steps mentioned in the page https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

Debugging in a physical device I found that the issue is in the next command of the IabHelper class:

```
mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

I noticed that it is not working because the program does not stop at either of the two methods of the ServiceConnection instance, that is to say, it does not stop at onServiceConnected() nor onServiceDisconnected()

I made a test using the same command directly in my Activity and the bind with the in-app billing service was successful.

So, the bind is working if it is requested from the Activity but it is not working when it is requested from the IabHelper class.

My question is, how can I bind my activity to the billing service from the IabHelper class?

Here is the code to call the startSetup method from IabHelper:

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, publicKey);

mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
    {
        if(!result.isSuccess())
        {
            mHelper=null;
            return;
        }

        if (mHelper == null) return;
    }
});
```

This is the code within IabHelper class to bind to service:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
List<ResolveInfo> intentServices = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(serviceIntent, 0);
if (intentServices != null && !intentServices.isEmpty())
{
    // service available to handle that Intent
    mContext.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

And here is the code that I used to bind to the service directly from the activity:

```
private IInAppBillingService mService;

ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection()
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        mService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,IBinder service)
    {
        mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }
};

Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
this.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what `mContext` in IabHelper class? is it "instanceof" Activity?

Answer (score 0):

I just realize my mistake, I was calling the queryInventoryAsync method before the startSetup get finished.

This was my mistake:

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
    {
        if(!result.isSuccess())
        {
            mHelper=null;
            return;
        }
    }
});

try {mHlpr.queryInventoryAsync(true, itemList, mQueryListener);}
catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

To correct, I changed the code to:

```
mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result)
    {
        if(!result.isSuccess())
        {
            mHelper=null;
            return;
        }
        else if(result.isSuccess())
        {
            try {mHlpr.queryInventoryAsync(true, itemList, mQueryListener);}
            catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
});
```

When I tested the bind directly from the activity, I had removed the command for the query, this is the reason it worked from the activity; when I was testing from the IabHelper class I was calling the query command